# SQL trigger leaves last matching row untouched

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

This is a trigger used to add the number of pages when a document's metadata row is added to a table.

```
USE [DD1234]
GO
/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[AfterIns_Pages_ABC_LandCont]    Script Date: 10/02/2014 16:30:33     ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[AfterIns_Pages_ABC_LandCont]
   ON  [dbo].[PVDM_DOCS_1234_13]
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

UPDATE D
SET D.DOCINDEX13 = O.Tot_Pages
FROM dbo.PVDM_DOCS_1234_13 D, 
(SELECT DOCID, Sum(PAGES) AS Tot_Pages FROM dbo.PVDM_OBJS_1234_13
GROUP BY DOCID) O
WHERE D.DOCID = O.DOCID 
AND D.DOCINDEX13 IS NULL
END
GO
```

So basically after a row (or many) are added to the PVDM_DOCS_1234_13 table, use the DOCID from that table to match the same DOCID in the Object (PVDM_OBJS_1234_13) table to retrieve the PAGES value, and then insert that into DOCINDEX13 (the field where we're storing the user visible page count) where DOCINDEX13 is null.

If a batch of 5, or 500 rows are inserted into PVDM_DOCS_1234_13, the last one inserted never gets the page count inserted, it remains NULL.  All the rest get the page count inserted.  Cannot figure out why the last row always gets left behind.

Note I'm an SQL novice, this was coded by someone no longer available.

Any ideas why this would work for all new rows except the last one inserted?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is that DOCINDEX13`is not`NULL` on the row being updated.  Without sample data, it is had to see what is going wrong.

By the way, I'd be inclined to write this query as:

```
with toupdate as (
      select d.*, sum(pages) over (order by docid) as tot_pages
      from  dbo.PVDM_DOCS_1234_13
     )
update toupdate
    set docindex13 = tot_pages
    where docindex13 is null;
```

As a general rules in SQL, don't use commas in the `from` clause.  Always use explicit `join` syntax.